# How to pull and restart my custom docker image from dockerhub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have paid version of docker hub.

I started my dockerfile from docker hub by:

```
sudo docker pull myname/demo-test:latest
sudo docker run -d -p 4444:4444 myname/demo-test
```

And it is working fine.

A created new version (new latest tag) and now, I would like to pull and restart my container.

How can I do it?

I tryied:

```
sudo docker pull myname/demo-test:latest
sudo docker restart ID
```

... but still old version is running.

Comment: I suggest you run `docker images` and inspect the image IDs directly. Then you'll really know what image you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pulling the latest tag again, stop the existing container. and execute the run command again.

```
sudo docker run -d -p 4444:4444 myname/demo-test
```

Comment: Ahh yeah of course, the `docker restart` command restarts a *container*. It does not then use the new image. To use the new image you need to stop and start.